# adding columns with alter table error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Ok I'm trying to add these columns to that table but it says I have a syntax error, Please let me know whats wrong

```
ALTER TABLE equipomulti ADD 
marca VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
serie VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
modelo VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
fechaAd DATE NULL ,
costo DOUBLE NULL ,
observacion VARCHAR(500) NULL ;
```

Comment: For future reference, if you include your error output, it will help the SO community give you a faster and better answer.

Comment: Ok sir, thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to wrap multiple columns in parens, try:

```
ALTER TABLE equipomulti ADD 
(marca VARCHAR(45),
serie VARCHAR(45),
modelo VARCHAR(45),
fechaAd DATE,
costo DOUBLE,
observacion VARCHAR(500)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your query.  First, you are incorrectly using the `NULL` operator in your `ALTER TABLE` statement.  To instruct MySQL to allow `NULL` values you don't need to specify anything explicitly, it will handle this by default.  Second, to add multiple columns in one `ALTER TABLE` statement, you should be using `ADD COLUMN` followed by the information for each new column, rather than just listing name.  Change your query to this:

```
ALTER TABLE equipomulti
ADD COLUMN marca VARCHAR(45),
ADD COLUMN serie VARCHAR(45),
ADD COLUMN modelo VARCHAR(45),
ADD COLUMN fechaAd DATE,
ADD COLUMN costo DOUBLE,
ADD COLUMN observacion VARCHAR(500);
```